# Kafka To S3 Connector

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Let assume we are using Kafka S3 Sink Connector in a Standalone mode.
As it's written on the confluent page, it has exactly once delivery garantee. 
I don't understand how does it work... 
If for example - at some point of time, the connector wrote messages to the S3, but didn't manage to commit offsets to the Kafka topic and crushed. 
The next time it starts up, it should process previous messages again?
Or does it use transactions internally?

Comment: Did you read the blog? https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-to-amazon-s3-exactly-once

Comment: @cricket_007 Great article, thank you! Now, I got the full picture, how does it work.